# dwa_local_planner penalize POSITIVE x

Tags: ros, navigation, youbot, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am currently working in a student project and want to be able to navigate with the youbot from KUKA.

Everything works fine with the dwa_local_planner but in my specific case, I need the robot to drive backwards since the laserscanner is mounted at the back.

I wanted to adapt the source code of the dwa_local_planner to my needs, but I could not find out where the variable 'penalize_negative_x' is used. My plan was to start from there on to penalize **POSITIVE** x.

I am also quite new to ROS and seem to be a bit helpless. Maybe you can give me some advice, how I can force the dwa_local_planner to drive backwards.

Thanks for your reply and kind regards,

Raphael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211654/dwa_local_planner-penalize-positive-x/) by [Rapha811](https://answers.ros.org/users/22846/rapha811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two possible solutions:

1 - Turn the reference frame around so that the back is now the front.

2 - Set your possible x velocities to reflect the possible directions, i.e. /min_vel_x=-1.0 (or whatever) and /max_vel_x to 0.0.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rapha811](https://answers.ros.org/users/22846/rapha811/) on 2015-06-23**:
Ok, so I tried the first solution and got it working, but the robot still moves forward from time to time although he could turn and move backwards, if he prefered it.

So, are negative x really penalized by the dwa_local_planner?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-23**:
Yes, this is a general preference to make the robot drive in the way that the sensors are pointed.

**Comment by [Rapha811](https://answers.ros.org/users/22846/rapha811/) on 2015-06-23**:
So, if I tell move_base to use two sensors (one pointing forward, one backwards) the robot will not prefer any direction? This is what i am currently doing. Then I should just remove the sensor pointing forward (it's only a kinect I don't want to be relying on) and the robot should move backwards?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-23**:
No. The preference to move forward assumes that you have sensors pointed forward (relative to the reference frame).

**Comment by [Rapha811](https://answers.ros.org/users/22846/rapha811/) on 2015-06-24**:
Okay thanks. I will keep an eye on the robots movement and work with what I got for now.